# How to configure the image or image view so that the image keeps its aspect ratio no matter what the size of the image view is?

Tags: ios, swift, image, aspect-ratio

I put an image view in a static table view cell. The image is now being stretched to fit the whole view. I want the image to:

- be centered in the image view
- be in the largest size possible but
- not exceed the bounds of the image view and
- keeps the aspect ratio of the image

First I went to the docs of `UIImageView`. But didn't find anything useful. Then I looked at the docs of `UIImage` and found `UIImageResizingMode`. But that enum only contains `Stretch` and `Tile`, which is not what I wanted. I then found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510807/how-to-set-the-image-into-fit-screen-in-the-image-view) which told me to

```
logo.contentMode = .Center
```

But the image is still stretched. I then tried this

```
logo.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
```

But the result is the same.

Please tell me a good way to do this!

Additional info:

The image view has the following constraints:

[image]

Comment: .contentMode is the correct property. Try  logo.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit. Also, when are you setting the property? initWithFrame? The correct place is viewDidLoad in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`.

Comment: You're welcome. 
[Another explanation.](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/ad9aada53c22d024b6519e241e386984971bcbad/68747470733a2f2f646576656c6f7065722e6170706c652e636f6d2f6c6962726172792f696f732f646f63756d656e746174696f6e2f57696e646f777356696577732f436f6e6365707475616c2f5669657750475f6950686f6e654f532f4172742f7363616c655f6173706563742e6a7067)